# Can't run new Angular CLI project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I've got a homework assignment for a job interview. It needs to be done in Angular, so I figured I'd quickly upgrade Node.js, NPM and Angular CLI before I start. It looks like that was a bad idea.

After running my command: `ng new project-name --style scss` everything seems to create itself just fine. But when I run `ng serve` I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot find module 'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin'
Error: Cannot find module 'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andybarratt/dev/project-name/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-
configs/production.js:13:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/andybarratt/dev/project-name/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/webpack-
configs/index.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
```

I can't find anything with this error involving Angular anywhere. As I say, it's a completely clean project; I haven't even begun coding yet.

Running `ng --version` gives me this:

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.6.6
Node: 9.4.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.6
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Help?

Comment: Check your packages.  The node_modules is looking for a uglifyjs-webpack-plugin.  It's either broken and/or missing.  The plugin could've changed, name change etc. endless options.  But everyone would be complaining.  I would either create a new directory see if the problem persist and/or clean out this directory and redo the Angular CLI instructions

Comment: You could also not use the CLI, developing Angular projects doesn't require the CLI, it's just a scaffolding tool

Comment: I've tried deleting and starting from scratch a few times, seems to be consistent.  I know I don't need CLI, I just find it's easier to get a consistent working project this way as I often get it wrong...  well, you know, it's worked up until now.

Comment: I've just found the exact same issue, it's installed in my node_modules folder just fine.

Comment: Of course scaffolding tools are amazing if they work :).  Sounds like it could be a versioning thing.  I am at work and locked down with NPM.  I would recommend trying to get an older version, you may have the latest beta.

Comment: I assume you did npm install -g '@angular-cli', I would do something like npm uninstall -g @anuglar-cli, reinstall but call out the specific version, 1.6.^ to get the latest from 1.6

Comment: Ignore the '@angular-cli' thought I was calling out a user, just drop the ''

Comment: I too am getting errors, have tried nuking node_modules and installing again. Even updated node and npm. ng serve continues to say it cannot find the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin module.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/217

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was just called out on their GitHub account, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9427.

Just get an earlier version, and/or fix their issue and put up a pull request (PR).

Comment: Ah, well that makes sense, I'm not going crazy!

Comment: Was just going to say I assume this is down to the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin 1.1.7 release an hour ago...

Comment: Yep happens from time to time.  Trying a prior version of the Angular CLI would resolve the issue.  Problem is you run into this issue in production from time to time.

Comment: npm i --save-dev uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.1.6 temporarily fixes the issue

Answer (score 13):

Add `"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.1.6"` to your package.json for now until they fix dependency issue ( https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9427 )

Also you can use command `npm i --save-dev uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.1.6`instead of edditing package.json manually as @Botonomous and @toughskin mentioned

Comment: Or use this: npm i --save-dev uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.1.6

Answer (score 1):

I have been fighting this issue for an hour. I found the issue [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/217) by using timjklein36's comment. I was able to fix the issue by rolling back to a previous version using:

```
npm i --save-dev uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.1.6
```

All credit to timjklein36 on GitHub for this answer. I just hope I can save some one some time.

Answer (score 1):

As the latest

**`uglifyjs-webpack-plugin`** has release a 1.1.8 version that should fix this problem.

You can force your local install to use this version by following these steps:

```
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.1.8 --save
npm uninstall uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.1.8 --save
```

By installing and uninstalling a specific version you will update your local npm cache to resolve matching ranges to that version.

I'd like to remind everyone that you only have reproducible installs if you use a lockfile. Both NPM v5+ and Yarn support lockfiles. If your CI works one day but not the next and you did not change your code or package.json, it is likely because one of your dependencies had a bad release and you did not have a lockfile.

It is your responsibility as a library consumer to use lockfiles. No one wants to do a release with bugs but it sometimes happens, and the best we can do is to fix it as fast as possible with a new release. When you have a couple of thousand total dependencies it is only a matter of time until one of them has a bad release.

Answer is taken from **[Can't serve due to uglifyjs-webpack-plugin 1.1.7 release](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9427)**